# Need help to make SQL procedure using Northwind DB?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, northwind

I've been trying to make a sql query to create a stored procedure to help me get all productID and the first date when it was bought, using Northwind data base.

The Selection must not have repeated values (This is where I've been struggling)

I have tried "Distinct" or "inner join (select ....)"

**Northwind Tables used:**

Order Details -> has ProductID and OrderID

OrderID -> has OrderDate

**This is what I've got so far:**

```
Create PROC GetProducts
as

   Select DISTINCT Products.ProductID, Orders.OrderDate 
   from [Order Details]
   inner join Products on [Order Details].ProductID = Products.ProductID
   inner join Orders on [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID

Exec GetProducts
```

OutPut:

[image: not expected OutPut]

The output should look like this, without reapeated values

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (SQL Server?)

Answer (score 1):

you need to do so using group by :

```
SELECT
    Products.ProductID
    , MIN(Orders.OrderDate)
FROM [Order Details]
INNER JOIN Products
    ON [Order Details].ProductID = Products.ProductID
INNER JOIN Orders
    ON [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID
GROUP BY Products.ProductID;
```